# Adding a delta function to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics, dirac-delta

So say I have a differential equation of the form:
$$
\left(\alpha \frac{d^2}{dx^2}+fx^2 \right)y(x)=\lambda y(x)
$$
Whose solutions are known (a Gaussian multiplying a Hermite polynomial.)

I am now curious how adding a delta function effects the solutions to this equation. So I am interested in figuring out the solutions to:
$$
\left(\alpha \frac{d^2}{dx^2}-g \delta(x)+fx^2 \right)y(x)=\lambda y(x)
$$

I can see that to the left and right of the origin, our original solution is still completely valid. At the origin however, we have an equation that approaches negative infinity from the delta potential. I can't really see if the solutions change at all from the added function, or if they do change if I could find the new solution using the original solution.

Comment: Generically, the effect of a $\delta$-function is to add an _internal_ boundary condition, i.e. a constraint on $y(x)$. More precisely, it enforces a jump discontinuity in $y'(x)/y(x)$ at $x=0$. To see this, integrate both sides of Schrodinger's equation from $x=-\epsilon$ to $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: So are the solutions completely changed? Or is it enough to piece together two of the solutions to the original equation, each with a different constant out front. For example: $$y(x)=A\psi_{osc}(x) \theta(-x)+B\psi_{osc}(x) \theta(x)$$

Comment: Correct: you know the energy of the particle and you want $\Psi$ to vanish at infinity, so the two functions can only differ by a constant. The situation would be different if you had two delta-functions (do you see why?)

Comment: Two delta functions would force discontinuities in $$y'(x)/y(x)$$ at the two points of the delta functions, so we would have to use three different oscillator pieces?

Comment: It's a little more than that. For the solutions on the left and right, you still have to have $y(x)\to 0$ at infinity; that means that you'll still get the usual harmonic oscillator eigenfunctions in those regions. But the middle region has a finite width and so the boundary conditions are of a different type. Consequently, we'd need to consider _two_ solutions in the middle. (It's the same issue as in a finite square well: outside the well, there only can be one solution; inside, there are two.)